# how should I unwrap this? in XCode 6

Tags: swift, xcode6

[image: timer app unwrap error]

this is just one example, I've multiple errors that suggest that things are not unwrapped. what am i writing wrongly?

UPDATE:

if anyone is interested, this is how i managed to unwrap it

```
if let stopTimer = timerController?.stopWatchTimer {
        NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(stopTimer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
        self.timerController!.timerDelegate = TimerRunning(timerController: self.timerController);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried 'timerController.stopWatchTimer!' (add exclamation mark)?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. Thats the suggestion XCode gave, which end up making it having 2 exclamation mark which doesn't make sense.

Comment: You just need one exclamation mark. You can surely edit away the extra '!', right? Which version of XCode you are using?

Comment: You do a lot "forced unwrapping" in your code (the "!") and it would work with your current problem too, but I strongly suggest you to learn what Optionals are and how you can work with them. You can find a good explanation in this blog post: http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/06/11/understanding-optionals-in-swift/